# display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener) doesn't handle event, if it is predefined hotkeys

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, keyevent

I have a trouble with handling key presses. My plugin must log every keyboard actions of user. So, I created handler win methods:

```
private Display display;

public ActionsRecorder() {
    display = Display.getCurrent();
    if (display == null) {
        display = Display.getDefault();
    }
}

public void handleKeyPress() throws ExecutionException {
    display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, this);
}

@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {  
    System.out.println(event.keyCode);
}
```

So, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, both presses are processed correctly. But if I press hot keys for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is processed. 
I think that another default handler catches event and assign `event.doit` value to `false`.

How to fix it? Are there another ways to create global (in ide window) logger?

**UPD**: Baz, thanks for help. But my problem is that eclipse (luna) doesn't call .handleEvent(e) method, if pressed hotkey.
Where you add listener in plugin lifecycle?

Comment: You can check if `ctrl` is pressed by comparing `Event#stateMask` to `SWT.CTRL`. `ctrl` + `a` works just fine for me.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was a plugin. Can't answer this then atm. BTW: you can use the comments to reply to people. If you use @USERNAME (e.g. @Baz) that user will get a notification as well.